# QxcbConnection error - CloudCompare won't launch

Tags: ubuntu, launch, snapcraft

I installed CloudCompare on my ubuntu machine using snap but I cannot launch the application. I get the following error message:

> QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0
>   Aborted (core dumped)

If I enter `$sudo cloudcompare.CloudCompare` instead of just `cloudcompare.CloudCompare`, I get the same with one more line that is :

> mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied

Even when changing acces control and permissions this won't go away.

I have the following GPU: NVIDIA GF106GL (Quadro 2000)

And I am on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I tried changing the access privileges, removing and re-installing both snapd and cloudcompare, updating my GPU drivers but nothing works.

If anyone has an idea, I would be relieved to hear it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow installing Meshlab with snap fixed the issue for me : after the installing process was completed, I tried launching CloudCompare again and it works !

Hopefully, this will be useful to someone else :)